Problem with optimizer and workfiles in Greenplum
I found two problems in my Greenplum case:
create table table1  (
id int4,
child_id int4 default 1
);

create table table2  (
id int4
);

insert into table1(id) values(1),(1),(2),(3),(4);

insert into table2(id) select generate_series(1, 1000000000);


explain analyze select * from
(select * from table1 
where child_id = 0) t1
left join
(select id, row_number() over(partition by id) as rn from table2) t2
on t1.id = t2.id and t2.rn = 1;

P.S: this data is for illustrating the example.

in the last query the query crashes with the error "workfile per query size limit exceeded" which I can't influence on this server. The server has 126 segments and 43 GB limit per segment. The distribution of tables is correct. The size of table 2 also can't be reduced. How can I bypass the error without changing the server settings?

The left part of the left join returns 0 rows and the query should logically be completed, but this does not happen in the GPORCA optimizer goes to scan table 2. In the Postgres optimizer the query works.



You shouldn't tag PostgreSQL. That error is Greenplum specific.
